# popNavigationItemAnimated error

Tags: iphone

I am getting an odd error:

2009-09-12 18:47:15.967 CraigsAlerts[10057:207] *** -[UINavigationController popNavigationItemAnimated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x191c7e0
2009-09-12 18:47:15.968 CraigsAlerts[10057:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UINavigationController popNavigationItemAnimated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x191c7e0'

My app is navigation based, and at the point I make this call I am 4 levels deep.  The call looks like:

```
[self.navigationController popNavigationItemAnimated:YES];
```

I do get a warning on that line:

warning: 'UINavigationController' may not respond to '-popNavigationItemAnimated:', which is the part that is really throwing me.  I am in my view code at the time, and I use popNavigationItemAnimated in other area's without this warning.

I am able to call the `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`without warning or incident, which leads me to believe my navigation controller is intact.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the popNavigationItemAnimated: is used for a UINavigationItem only not for a UINavigationController object.

If you're looking for a way to pop navigation views than try a 
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; instead.